# Reddit pagination before = NULL

Tags: php, pagination, reddit

I am trying to paginate a set of results from returned from the reddit API but the before parameter always returns NULL so I can load the next page.

Here is my pagination link:

This always contains a value for the `after` parameter

```
<a href="index.php?count=<?php echo $count ?>&after=<?php echo $response->data->after; ?>&limit=<?php echo $limit ?>" class="pagination-load-more">Previous</a>
```

This `before` always is empty

```
<a href="index.php?count=<?php echo $count ?>&before=<?php echo $response->data->before; ?>&limit=<?php echo $limit ?>" class="pagination-load-more">Load More</a>
```

From research I have seen that I need to parse in the count variable to tell the API how many posts have been displayed and where to start the next page from.

Can anyone help me with this please?